How to optimize mongodb inserts across multiple collections in C#?
I need to insert records into multiple collections within the same MongoDB database. Each record can be inserted into a different collection. More than one structure is trying to do this operation at the same time and the wait queue is swelling.
And after then there are latency more than 5 secs about getting information wait queue and exceptions like MongoWaitQueueFullException or TimeoutException because of the wait queue.
I can get rid of WaitQueueFullException by increasing MaxConnectionPoolSize, but then I start to get timeout while getting information from wait queue, wait queue timeout is 5 seconds, I think even this is too much.
How can I prevent this wait time?
    public class WriteOperation(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection, IEnumerable<BsonDocument> documents)
    {
        private IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> Collection { get; } = collection;
        private IEnumerable<BsonDocument> Documents { get; } = documents;
    
        public async Task WriteAsync(InsertManyOptions options)
            => await Collection.InsertManyAsync(Documents, options);
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(Dictionary<string, List<TTick>> groupedTicks)
    {
        var writeOperations = from groupedTick in groupedTicks
            let collectionName = groupedTick.Key + "_ticks"
            let collection = GetCollection(collectionName)
            let documents = groupedTick.Value.Select(x => x.ToBsonDocument()).ToList()
            select new WriteOperation(collection, documents);

        var tasks = writeOperations.Select(op => op.WriteAsync(_insertingOptions)).ToArray();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> GetCollection(string collectionName)
    {
        if (_collections.TryGetValue(collectionName, out var collection))
            return collection;

        collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
        _collections[collectionName] = collection;

        return collection;
    }


How large is the database?  Large databases take a lot of memory and can take a lot of processing time to run queries.  When you attempt to run multiple queries at the same time the amount of memory requires increase as well as the time to complete.  Large Database should be run on machines with the fastest processor you can get with as maqny number of cores you can buy and loaded with as much memory that the machine can hold.  There is no way of optimizing mongodb.  If you still have issues than you should not be using mongodb and instead using a db which is designed for very large databases.

Try limiting the level of concurrency, and tell us if this solves the problem.

@jdweng MongoDB was invented to handle very large databases. However, instead of buying the fastest processor you can get it provides sharding which distributes the database over multiple (cheap) computers. That's one of the differences to other databases.

I don't know your database design, but I don't see the reason why you use multiple collections. Try to write all data into one collection and gain from Bulk operation. Note, if you can wait for MongoDB version 8, it will support Bulk operations to multiple collections.

read this article https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/faq/#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-the-.net-c--driver-

also pay attention that session (and all related options in insert options) is not thread safe

I'm starting to think that the problem is network related, because I have no problem with a local mongo server with the same configurations and similar hardware.

@WernfriedDomscheit : So isn't MongoDB slow?

@jdweng I have an application running at MongoDB which inserts every day 7.5 Billion(!) documents into it, it has a size of 35 TB. Before it was running on Oracle which run into an overload. I cannot confirm that MongoDB would be a slow database.

I am now 100% sure that the problem is not in the code or Mongo server, but in the network.
